# limit of character to display in HTML or php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to modify **cmscanvas**

> cmscanvas.com

built in code igniter.

when i use this syntax in html file `{{ service_description }}` where `service_description` is name of field it display the text in that field.

i am trying to limit of character to display but i can't as i can't use PHP here.

how to limit the character by html or some other way?

i am trying to find out solution but can't and there is not special help on internet for this too.

Thanks

Comment: @SuperDJ Per the question, "I can't use PHP here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution with javascript :

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var i;
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
      if(divs[i].className == 'myclass') {
        divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.substring(0,200);
      }
    }
 </script>
```